# SQL Statement Question - How to retrieve records of a table where the primary key does not exist in another table as a foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table (TableA) where the primary key exists as a foreign key on another table (TableB).  I am trying to write a SQL query (I am using SQL Server 2005) that will find all of the records in TableA where the primary key does not exist in TableB as a foreign key (we'll say joining on TableAID).  I suspect it will use an outer join, but I have been struggling.  Can anyone help a SQL newb out?

Comment: @All, So which of the below answers would be considered the best for performance?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT A.*
FROM TableA AS A
LEFT JOIN TableB AS B ON (A.ID = B.TableAID)
WHERE B.TableAID IS NULL
```

Comment: @DaMartyr, you are correct. A `LEFT JOIN` is an OUTER JOIN. Technically `LEFT OUTER JOIN`.

Comment: This may be less efficient than the not exists approach in the other answers.

Answer (score 4):

You can use NOT EXISTS

```
SELECT columnlist
FROM TableA
WHERE NOT EXISTS(
   SELECT * FROM TableB
   WHERE TableB.column = TableA.column)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is nearly natural language in SQL ("WHERE NOT EXISTS"):

```
SELECT A.*
FROM TableA AS A
WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT 1
                   FROM TableB
                   WHERE TableA.ID = B.TableAID
                 )
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Select * from TableA 
where 
 TableA.TableAID not in (select TableB.TableAID from TableB)
```

Comment: This will perform considerably worse than the not exists query suggested by others.

Comment: This will deliver an empty result if TableB.TableAID is null for at least one record.

Comment: I really try not to use IN if it can be avoided since it is such a slow operation, and doesn't play nice with NULL.

Comment: @Frank but how do I know that from his question???  He said the data integrity issue is the opposite of what you are saying is a concern.

Comment: @Achilles - Yes, he did not state if there are nulls in TableB.TableAID. But he also did not state there are no nulls. And the NOT EXISTS or LEFT JOIN/IS NULL solutions deliver a correct result in both cases, and the NOT IN() solution delivers an empty result if there are nulls - which is just wrong (assuming there are IDs in TableA that have no matching keys in TableB).